# typedef in C++ - Need help understanding

Tags: c++, typedef

I understand the general concept of typedef. But I came across this and don't know what it means:

```
typedef PackedIntItem <uint16_t, uint16_t, 0x0FFF, 0xF000, SomeClassName, uint16_t, 0xFFFF> SomeTypeName;
```

Comment: remove `typdef` and ask yourself "What variable do I get?"

Comment: Regarding the update, how familiar are you with templates?

Comment: Not too familiar unfortunately. Know the basic concepts but have not had to deal with it on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef <old name> <new name>;
```

Means I want to give a new name to a data type. Usually because

- old name was very long
- we want to abstract the name so we can easily change from one type to another

In you case you have use case #1

```
typedef PackedIntItem<uint16_t, uint16_t, 0x0FFF, 0xF000, SomeClassName, uint16_t, 0xFFFF> SomeTypeName;
```

old name is very long. Now your question comes down to - what the heck is that long name?

its a templated data type. That means that came form something like this

```
template<type T1, type T2> class Elephant
{
     T1 widget;
     T2 oleAtIt;
}
```

but with a lot more Ts in your case. Now when you do

```
Elephant<int, char> dumbo;
```

You actually get an instance of a class as though you had declared

```
class Elephant
{
   int widget;
   char oleAtIt;
}
```

This is what you are using when you see `std::vector<int> listInt;`

In your case somebody made a template with an unusually large number of parameters.See if you can find its declaration

Templating is a HUGE topic. Google a lot. Have fun

Comment: `typedef <old name> <new name>;` is *not* the real syntax and is just confounding for e.g. function pointers. Once I finally discovered the real `typedef` syntax (=the syntax of any variable declaration) what I never understood was why had I been lied for my entire life about it.